# How to load external properties file with Java without rebuilding the Jar?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I use gradle which structures projects in maven style so I have the following

`src/main/java/Hello.java` and `src/main/resources/test.properties`

My `Hello.java` look like this

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties configProperties = new Properties();
        ClassLoader classLoader =  Hello.class.getClassLoader();
        try {
            configProperties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("test.properties"));
            System.out.println(configProperties.getProperty("first") + " " + configProperties.getProperty("last"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. however I want to be able to point to `.properties` file outside of my project and I want to it to be flexible enough that I can point to any location **without rebuilding the jar every time**. Is there a way to this without using a File API and passing file path as an argument to the main method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one, which will first try to load properties file from project home directory so that you don't have to rebuild jar, if not found then will load from classpath

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String configPath = "test.properties";

        if (args.length > 0) {
            configPath = args[0];
        } else if (System.getenv("CONFIG_TEST") != null) {
            configPath = System.getenv("CONFIG_TEST");
        }

        File file = new File(configPath);
        try (InputStream input = file.exists() ? new FileInputStream(file) : Hello.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configPath)) {
            Properties configProperties = new Properties();
            configProperties.load(input);
            System.out.println(configProperties.getProperty("first") + " " + configProperties.getProperty("last"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can send the properties file path as argument or set the path to an environment variable name `CONFIG_TEST`

Comment: This wont give me a flexibility of specifying .properties files anywhere I want right (something I mentioned in my question.) I also mentioned that I am looking for a solution without using a File API and passing file path as an argument to the main method

Comment: @user1870400 Added path as argument

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Again as I mentioned in the question I am looking for a solution "without" using a File API and passing file path as an argument to the main method.

Comment: Oh, sorry. you can  set an environment variable that contains the path, from the program read the environment variable to get the path

Comment: @user1870400 If you do not pass a path and do not use a file API, how do you imagine the magic to happen?

Comment: I want to pass file path through system variable I think.

Answer (score 1):

[Archaius](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius) may be complete overkill for such a simple problem, but it is a great way to manage external properties. It is a library for handling configuration: hierarchies of configuration, configuration from property files, configuration from databases, configuration from user defined sources. It may seem complicated, but you will never have to worry about hand-rolling a half-broken solution to configuration again. The Getting Started page has a section on [using a local file as the configuration source](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki/Getting-Started#using-a-local-file-as-the-configuration-source).

Comment: I dont know if it is simple. I tried to look for solution without using external libraries but I wasn't able to come across any. so if it's simple could you please tell me how to do it without an External library? I will certainly consider Archaius once my project gets more mature.